# What is Hinduism's view on veganism?

Tags: food

Veganism is refraining from consuming dairy products.

There are spiritual benefits of vegetarianism, meaning it gives lots of punya.

But does following veganism give punya?

Comment: Veganism is not only consuming milk products. The definition you gave is wrong. There is a broader definition of that term. Modify with proper term and it won't be a duplicate.

Comment: Vegan environmentalist life is best for planet & animals. It is most best 